# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AppLocal.Core'

Tags: sql-server, olap

i get this error in visual studio 2015. I want to make an OLAP cube using SQL server 2016 RC0. I can't find any solution to this error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AppLocal.Core, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. Nie można odnaleźć określonego pliku.            0

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution:

> Delete the folder, %Windows%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.DeploymentEngine
>   After deleting the folder, you should be able to deploy or build the project right away. No restart or reinstallation is required.
>   Applies to: SQL Server 2016 RC1 only.

On windows 10 folder is in path:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\

So just you need to delete folder: Microsoft.AnalysisServices.DeploymentEngine

AND ALL WORKED :)

Comment: Thanks.  I found the same advice in the release notes for SQL 2016 at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn876712.aspx